# Is there a typo in this question about double integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

The question is as follows:

Prove that if $f$ is continuous on an interval $[a,b]$ then:

$2\int_a^b f(x)dx\cdot\int_x^bf(y)dy=[\int_a^bf(x)dx]^2$.

I tried figuring out what this means but I don't know what is meant by the $x$ subscript. I tried the following which makes clear it's nonsense but I don't know if there's something I'm failing to understand.

Let $x=b$:
$$2\int_a^b f(x)dx\cdot0=[\int_a^bf(x)dx]^2$$
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx=0$$

But this is clearly false. Use $f(x)=1$ on any interval with $b>a$ and it's obvious. So what am I doing wrong, and if nothing, does anyone recognize what the question was supposed to be?

Comment: Let $F(x) =\int_{a} ^{x} f(t) \, dt$ then your equation is $$2\int_{a}^{b}f(x)(F(b)-F(x))\,dx=(F(b)-F(a))^{2}$$ which should be easily handled by integration by parts.

Comment: The expression LHS is written badly. It should be written by placing $dy$ first and then $dx$ like $$\int_{a}^{b}\left(f(x)\int_{x}^{b}f(y)\,dy\right)\,dx$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x$ is only "declared" as a variable in one place - as the dummy variable of the first integral. Everywhere else, it has *no meaning*. So we have to assume that anything that uses $x$ is actually part of that integral.

Hence, you should read $\int_a^b f(x)dx\cdot\int_x^bf(y)dy$ as actually being $\int_a^b \left(f(x) \int_x^b f(y) dy \right) dx$.

For example, let $f(x) = x^2$ and $[a, b] = [0, 1]$. Then we are looking at, on the left side:

$$2\int_a^b f(x)dx\cdot\int_x^bf(y)dy = 2\int_0^1 \left( x^2 \times \int_x^1 y^2 dy \right) dx = 2\int_0^1 \left(x^2 \times \left[\frac{1}{3}y^3 \right]_x^1 \right) dx = 2\int_0^1 \left( x^2 (\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{3}x^3) \right) dx$$  and so forth.

Comment: But how can the $x$ from the first integral correspond with the other integral? Isn't that bad notation? Usually you get different results when you take things in and out of an integral, if they are not constant.

Comment: That's what I mean - the second integral is actually inside the other one. It's written kind of weirdly (normally you'd stick the $dx$ either just after the integral sign or right at the end) but there is literally no other way to interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

$x$ refers to the value taken in the outer integral. It might be easier to think about what it means by looking at summations first before looking at integrals. For example: $$\sum_{i=0}^3 \sum_{j=i}^3 \ \ j = (0+1+2+3)+(1+2+3)+(2+3)+3$$